# How to link to a .so library in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, linker

What I am trying to do is to link my project to a .so library that I have. Is it enough to add it in the Project Properties -> Linker, as I am doing with every static library (.lib), or is it another way to do it??

My project is an Win32 Console C++ Application.

Comment: What are you attempting to link it _to_, and what format is the `.so` file in?

Comment: I don't know about the format..how can I found out?

Comment: Easiest is to use the [file utility](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) to show it. Chances are though that it's a file type that cannot be linked on Windows at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Visual Studio to link to a .so file, because that's a Unix kind of shared library (and it will also be compiled for some Unix operating system). Visual Studio can only link for the Windows operating system. In this case, recompile your library to a windows .dll file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#File_naming